# Why when I create launch.json file in vscode debugger it installs a lot of dependencies

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

When I click to create a launch.json file I get this in the terminal.
This is normal ? or is something bad happening?

```
Installing C# dependencies...
Platform: win32, x86_64

Downloading package 'OmniSharp for Windows (.NET 4.6 / x64)' (38449 KB).................... Done!
Validating download...
Integrity Check succeeded.
Installing package 'OmniSharp for Windows (.NET 4.6 / x64)'

Downloading package '.NET Core Debugger (Windows / x64)' (45337 KB).................... Done!
Validating download...
Integrity Check succeeded.
Installing package '.NET Core Debugger (Windows / x64)'

Downloading package 'Razor Language Server (Windows / x64)' (62313 KB)..........
```

I'm already waiting 45 min

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a matter of waiting and the debugging panel would open